# API SMS Not sending From server

Tags: php, curl

In my code after final submit the page is loading too long time and returned with the error"Request Timeout. This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.".

When i am comment the line //curl_exec($ch); page working fine. and also i was checked that, The generated URL is working,while manually paste the url code in browser address bar. PHP CURL Extension also enabled correctly. please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    sms_test
</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php
$pass = "abc321";
$send = "BMSBMS";
$flash = "false";
$dest = 9994182471;
//$dest = 9994182471;
$senderId = "Bmstrans";

//Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.

$message = ("Your login OTP is : 12345.

-BMS/BHEL/TRICHY
");

//Define route 
$route = "2";
//Prepare you post parameters
$apiParams = array(
    'uname' => $senderId,
     'pass' => $pass,
    'send' => $send,
     'dest' => $dest,
    'msg' => $message,
   
);

//merge API url and parameters
$apiUrl = "https://www.instaalerts.zone/SendSMS/sendmsg.php?";
foreach($apiParams as $key => $val){
    $apiUrl .= $key.'='.urlencode($val).'&';
}
$Url = str_replace(" ","%20",$apiUrl);
echo $Url;

//API call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

  ?>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying via our service provider support team. They told that, There is no issue in server side. and also they told that, contact any other programmer to modify the program.

Comment: We cannot increase your PHP timeout for you. You should be able to set it in php.ini, or if you don't have access to that, via https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php. Have you done any research?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sir, While executing this code, the page is loading a long time and finally time out. there is no code output we got.